# Using a different activation function in ADALINE algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I've recently been trying to work on learning a couple things in machine learning, and I'm trying to understand how the adaline algorithm works and there is one thing that I still don't understand. In the particular tutorial that I am following, the linear activation function is just the identity function of the net input function, which looks pretty ridiculous in code :

```
def net_input(self, X):
      """Calculate net input"""
      return np.dot(X, self.weight[1:]) + self.weight[0]

def activation(self, X):
      """Compute linear activation"""
      return self.net_input(X)
```

So I was wondering, is this just a weird implementation of the adaline algorithm, or is it done this way because you can use other type of activation functions with this algorithm ?

Sorry if this sounds like a noob question, I tried googling it but I didn't find anything that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Adaline uses continuous predicted values (from the net input) to learn the model coefficients, which is more "powerful" since it tells us by "how much" we were right or wrong.

Comment: Check out the figure of Adaline  closely and you will get the answer ... https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/faq/diff-perceptron-adaline-neuralnet.md